# iPhone CameraOverlay view 20px gap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I have an app that uses the iPhone camera and puts an overlay over the camera. However it all works fine and i have managed to rotate the UIView to landscape but their is a 20px gap at the top of the view although i have set the positioning to (0,0,480,320).

```
starContainerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480.0, 320.0)]     autorelease]; 
 UIImageView *overlayViewNew = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,480.0,320.0)];
 UIImage *OverlayImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"overlay.png"] autorelease];
 overlayViewNew.image = OverlayImage;
 [starContainerView addSubview:overlayViewNew];
```

So as you can see above I have set the UIView and set the UIIMageView and assigned a UIImage to that UIImageview and then added it to a subview of the view.

Here is the code I use to rotate the View.

```
- (void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer
   didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
     if (fabsf(acceleration.x) > -1.0) {
       CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform =     CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));
       landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, +80.0, +100.0);
       [self.starContainerView setTransform:landscapeTransform];
     }
   }
```

I just cant seem to get it to fill that gap! Can i also say that no rocket science was involved whilst developing this but I still cant find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If was down to the following code. I played about with the figures below and this worked.

```
CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform =     CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90)); 
  landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, +80.0, +80.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

A 20px gap might have something to do with the status bar not being hidden properly. Make sure you have this in your info.plist:

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key> 
<true />
```

Comment: Yes i have already got this enabled in the plist file. However it does look like it could be something to do with the status bar as it is that size.